# Core Web API reading configuration values from incorrect deployment slot

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an application that was deployed via a deployment slot that is reading values from the incorrect place. I have an automated deployment going to my testing deployment slot and then I used the swap function in Azure portal to promote the build to production. When I look at each individual configuration section for each deployment slot my configuration values are different and they are all checked on as 'Deployment slot setting'. However, my production build continues to retrieve values that are only present in the testing slot. Did I miss something during the swap? I've tried restarting the service and no luck.

The value that is being returned when I query my configuration setting is not present in any deployment slot. I looked for it in source and it's not present. I'm baffled by this one.

Comment: If you dont to want the configuration values to be swapped, then you need to check(enable) the settings of [`Deployment slot setting`](https://i.imgur.com/RNhyHBR.png).

Comment: With that option the configuration values will remain in the same slot.

Comment: @Harshitha I did that as described in my original question.

Comment: I read it as checked off..Can you please share the screen shot of the settings.

Comment: Do you have web.config file?Make sure you have not set those values in that file.

Comment: @Harshitha Sorry poor choice of words. For every setting on each deployment slot this setting has the 'Deployment slot setting' enabled. My understanding is that this makes the value "sticky" to each environment.

Comment: @Harshitha No web.config I only used my app settings.Development.json during development. These keys are not even present in app settings.json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256542/discussion-between-harshitha-and-alex).

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to followup on this in case anyone else runs into something similar. The issue was an automated deployment with GitHub Actions that was reporting as correct but when really digging into the details the incorrect branch was being deployed after some recent changes to the way we deploy. An incorrect build with a hard-coded value stayed in production. Start from the basics and work your way up the deployment chain, don't take any OK/green status badges fool you!